# Unable to create CDATA section in XML using "xmlbuilder" node.js module

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, npm, xml-builder

I am using "xmlbuilder" node.js module to create xml file. I need to create a CDATA section as follows:

```
<notestext><![CDATA[{Notes Text}]]></notestext>
```

I referred the github [link](https://github.com/oozcitak/xmlbuilder-js/wiki#cdata-nodes), but didn't found any useful stuff.

How to create such CDATA section in an xml file using "xmlbuilder" node.js module?

```
let builder = require('xmlbuilder', { encoding: 'utf-8' });
let xml = builder.create('Slides');
xml.ele("notestext","<![CDATA[" + element.notes_text + "]]>");
xml.end({ pretty: true });

console.log(xml.toString());
```

Answer (score 5):

From [Doc](https://github.com/oozcitak/xmlbuilder-js/wiki#cdata-nodes) you posted

> CDATA Nodes CDATA nodes are created with the cdata function (can also
>   be abbreviated to dat or d). The value should not include CDATA
>   delimiters
>
> ```
> ele.dat('this will be surrounded by CDATA delimiters');
> ```

```
var builder = require('xmlbuilder', { encoding: 'utf-8' });

var xml = builder.create('slides');
xml.ele('notestext').dat('{Notes Text}');

xml.end({ 
  pretty: true,
  indent: '  '
});

console.log(xml.toString());
```

Comment: No such method found error is coming when applying "dat()" method. Please check

Comment: it worked for me **xmlbuilder@10.1.1**  **node v6.9.4** **npm v3.10.10**

Answer (score 2):

### Solution 1:

Utilize the `.cdata` (`.dat`, or `.d`) method and chain each method to generate the XML fragment. For instance:

**Javascript:**

```js
var builder = require('xmlbuilder');

var element = {
  notes_text: '<p>Hello <em>World</em></p>'
};

var xml = builder
    .create('slides', { version: '1.0', encoding: 'UTF-8', standalone: true })
    .ele('notestext')
    .cdata(element.notes_text)
    .end({ 
      pretty: true
    });

console.log(xml);
```

---

**Output**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<slides>
  <notestext>
    <![CDATA[<p>Hello <em>World</em></p>]]>
  </notestext>
</slides>
```

---

### Solution 2:

Another way to write it, which is more similar to your example, is as follows:

```js
var builder = require('xmlbuilder', { encoding: 'utf-8' });

var element = {
  notes_text: '<p>Hello <em>World</em></p>'
};

var xml = builder.create('slides');
xml.ele('notestext').cdata(element.notes_text);

xml.end({ 
  pretty: true
});

console.log(xml.toString());
```

**Note:** This example uses less method chaining than the previous example, however it does chain the `cdata` method to the `ele` method.

This prints the following:

```xml
<slides>
  <notestext>
    <![CDATA[<p>Hello <em>World</em></p>]]>
  </notestext>
</slides>
```

### Solution 3:

Alternatively, if you don't want to chain any methods you can do something like following:

```js
var builder = require('xmlbuilder');

var element = {
  notes_text: '<p>Hello <em>World</em></p>'
};

var rootElement = builder.create('slides');

var childElement = rootElement.ele('notestext')
childElement.cdata(element.notes_text);

rootElement.end({ 
  pretty: true
});

console.log(rootElement.toString());
```

This also prints the same output as *Solution 2*.

---

#### Additional information:

The docs describe the `.cdata` method as follows:

> **CDATA Nodes**
>
> CDATA nodes are created with the `cdata` function (can also be abbreviated to `dat` or `d`). The value should not include CDATA delimiters
>
> `ele.dat('this will be surrounded by CDATA delimiters');`

---